# activity indicator does not animating in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a requirement that when the user clicks a submit button on the Login screen, I need to animate a `UIActivityIndicator`, but - using the code below - it is not animating:

```
-(IBAction)loginButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [currenttextfield resignFirstResponder];
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
    BOOL valid=[self emailvalidate];

    if(valid) {
        if (!self.passwordstring.length ==0  && ![self.passwordstring isEqualToString:@" "] && ![self.passwordstring isEqualToString:nil] && !self.emailstring.length ==0  && ![self.emailstring isEqualToString:@" "] && ![self.emailstring isEqualToString:nil] ) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendDetails) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

This method first calls **EmailValidate** returning a `BOOL` value. If valid, **send details method** is called in which I am calling the repository to check the values. On completion of this, I stop the activity indicator. Does anyone know how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Check if you have connected the IBOutlet with indicator.

Comment: is a IBOUTLET connection? if it is, did you check the connection?

Comment: Check IBOutlet Connection for both button and spinner(activity indicator) connection and debug it step by step

Comment: its working for other button actions

Comment: do you use Modern Objective-C ? how do you @syntetize it?

Comment: yes obj-c by using nonatomic,strong properties

Comment: try [_spinner startAnimating];

Comment: ok simone i will test now

Answer (score 1):

if you have used interface builder for Activity indicator then define its IBOutlet and its property.

```
-(IBAction)loginButtonAction:(id)sender{

    [currenttextfield resignFirstResponder];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    BOOL valid=[self emailvalidate];
    if(valid) {
        if (!self.passwordstring.length ==0  && ![self.passwordstring isEqualToString:@" "] && ![self.passwordstring isEqualToString:nil] && !self.emailstring.length ==0  && ![self.emailstring isEqualToString:@" "] && ![self.emailstring isEqualToString:nil] ) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendDetails) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        }
    } }
```

Comment: i defined the property and also connected the outlet

Comment: I just checked its working. You just have to check the connection. One more thing i am just suspecting is use performSelector:withDelay method instead of the method you have used. That may provide 4 to 5 sec delay to start the animation.

Comment: post this answer its usefull